# Adding tables to form from text file C#

Tags: c#

I have a text file with two tables on it like this

```
1:"Transmitter",1,grid,32,6 

2:"Parameters", 2,list,64
```

I want to show the two table in my form, and if needed the user can add more tables to the text file. If the user adds more tables to the form then the additional tables will show in the form.

I am using tab control to add the tabs to the form specified from the file, and for the tables I am using data grid view

Here is my **code :**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        String line;
        String typeOfTable;
        int amountOfRows;
        int amountOfColumns;

        private const String TABS = "TABS";
        private const String TABLES = "TABLES";
        private const String GRID = "grid";
        private const String LIST = "list";

        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_TYPE = 2;
        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_ROWS = 3;
        private const int LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_COLUMNS = 4;
        private const int AMOUNT_Columns_IN_LIST = 2;


        String[] splitTableArray;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getFormContentFromFile();
        }

        private void getFormContentFromFile()
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("neo2G.res"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();

                    if (line.Equals(TABS))
                    {
                        while (!line.Equals(".."))
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();

                            if (!line.Equals(".."))
                            {
                                createTabInForm(line);

                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (line.Equals(TABLES))
                    {
                        while (!line.Equals(".."))
                        {
                            line = reader.ReadLine();

                            if (!line.Equals(".."))
                            {
                                splitTableLineToArray(line);
                                typeOfTable = splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_TYPE];
                                amountOfRows = int.Parse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_ROWS]);

                                if(typeOfTable.Equals(GRID))
                                {
                                    amountOfColumns = int.Parse(splitTableArray[LOCATION_TABLE_AMOUNT_COLUMNS]);
                                    dataGridView1.DataSource = createGridForForm(amountOfRows, amountOfColumns);
                                }

                                else if( typeOfTable.Equals(LIST))
                                {
                                    dataGridView1.DataSource = createListForForm(amountOfRows);

                                }
                                }
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        private void createTabInForm(String tabName)
        {
            tabName = Regex.Replace(tabName, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
            tabName = tabName.Trim(':', '"');
            TabPage myTabPage = new TabPage(tabName);
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
        }

        private void splitTableLineToArray(String tableLine)
        {
            splitTableArray = tableLine.Split(',');
        }

        public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
        {

            // Create the output table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

                   for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                // populate data row with values here
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }    

            return table;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method builds a DataTable of the data.
        /// </summary>
        public DataTable createListForForm(int rows)
        {

            // Create the output table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 1; i <= AMOUNT_Columns_IN_LIST ; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("My column " + i.ToString());
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                // populate data row with values here
                table.Rows.Add(dr);


            }
            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the problem? What is the question?

Comment: how do i add tables programatically from my text file

Comment: Well, you explained what you want to do, you showed code that pretty much does what you explained. So what exactly does not work? Do you get errors? Where does your code go wrong?

Comment: in the code i am adding the tabs programatically so i need to do the same thing with the tables

Answer (score 0):

Use the designer to add one or (better) two tables.

Analyse the code which is added by the designer and use this as a starting point to add your tables from your code.